# Exception with jbullet+lwjgl?

Tags: eclipse, opengl, nullpointerexception, lwjgl, bullet

I get an exception when trying to run my pretty much "hello world" sized project with jbullet and lwjgl in eclipse

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at gameVroom.Objects.ground(Objects.java:42)
    at gameVroom.MainThing.gameLoop(MainThing.java:50)
    at gameVroom.MainThing.main(MainThing.java:104)`

here's the source (again, pretty small I'm not dumping a full game to look through. Also, if there's a better place or way to ask this then please tell me.)

http://goo.gl/5C2bNJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A null pointer means that something wasn't properly initialized. Make sure(if using collections) that everything is properly allocated in said collection.

Comment: I figured it out when I woke up... I'm an idiot. I forgot to create a Set<RigidBody>, thanks!

Comment: @novasniff please don't forget to accept me as the answer. =)